# Multiple Microsoft-hosted agent pools within the same organisation

Tags: azure

In Azure you can define multiple agent pools.

However, when I click on "Add Pool" there are only 2 options, "Self Hosted" and "Azure virtual machine scale set":

[image]

It seems that the Microsoft-hosted agents are in the "Default pool".

However, we would like to be able to assign pools to different teams which are in the same organization.

Is that not possible? Are we thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a concept of agent pools for Microsoft-hosted agents, you just specify the image type you want to use [(more info here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Microsoft-hosted agents run on shared infrastructure and are reimaged after every run, so there is no inherent benefit of having them in a pool. If you do not need self-hosted agents (eg. for accessing resources in private networks) your users should just specify the image type they want to run their pipelines on.

Agent pools are usually used to group together self-hosted agents sharing properties like location or connectivity. For example, you could have one pool for generic agents running in Azure that have a static outbound IP address, a second pool running on-prem, and a third pool that has network connectivity to your ERP system and is extra beefy for building huge builds.

You can also use [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#capabilities) to further narrow down on different features  of self-hosted agents.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The reason would be to be able to dedicate an agent pool to a specific team so only they can make use of a set of resources.